# PHP Unique names for multiple submit buttons fails

Tags: php, button, unique

I am busy making a small search engine that gets info out of my DB. The next thing that has to happen, is that every searched record has the option to edit it. So I have to give every record a submit button with a unique name. This works fine, until I press the button. Then every button has the same name.

```
create form:"
<form sutff>
$t=0;
while (){<br/>
$t+=1;<br/>
input type="Submit" name="$t"/><br/>
}</form>
```

one pressed a button:

```
while($_POST[$t]>0){
  if (isset($_POST[$t])) { 
    do stuff
  }
  else{
    $_POST[$t]-=1;
  }
}
```

Don't worry about accolades, '' and "". I'll fix it myself.

Comment: You need to post your actual code. It's currently way too obscure for us to make sense of.

Answer (score 1):

A JavaScript approach goes like this:

```
<form name="form1" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="">
<input type="submit" value="submit this" onclick="document.form1.item_id.value = '<?php echo 16; ?>';">
<input type="submit" value="submit this" onclick="document.form1.item_id.value = '<?php echo 32; ?>';">
<input type="submit" value="submit this" onclick="document.form1.item_id.value = '<?php echo 48; ?>';">
</form>
```

On the server side:

```
<?php
$item_id = $_POST["item_id"];
?>
```

Another option, perhaps better since its 100% HTML+CSS solution, is to do something along these lines:

```
<style type="text/css">
.submit-button {
    .submit-button {
        /* WARNING: works only in standards compliance mode */
        text-indent: -1000px; /* this hides the button label */
        background: url("edit.gif") no-repeat; /* this places an icon inside the button */
        margin: 0; /* rest makes the button look CoOl */
        border: 1px solid;
        border-color: buttonhighlight buttonshadow buttonshadow buttonhighlight;
        padding: 0;
        width: 18px;
        height: 18px;
    }
</style>

<form name="form1" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="item_id" value="<?php echo 16; ?>" class="submit-button">
<input type="submit" name="item_id" value="<?php echo 32; ?>" class="submit-button">
<input type="submit" name="item_id" value="<?php echo 64; ?>" class="submit-button">
</form>
```

On the server side:

```
<?php
$item_id = $_POST["item_id"];
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a seperate form for each row, that way you can have hidden fields with data.

Another solution is to use an onclick event on the submitbutton to set a hidden field before continuing with the submit.

Naming the submitbutton should work though.

A third option is to not use submit at all but go for a plain button and use onclick to open an url instead.

A forth option is to fake the button with an image with a link around.

But with more information we might get some more ideas.

Comment: Two of these options are demonstrated in my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what you are asking

You can set a value for the submit button and read that

```
 <input type='submit' name='sub' value='edit' />
 <input type='submit' name='sub' value='search' />
```

And then in php you can do

```
if ($_POST['sub'] == "edit") { 
    //Do edits
}
else if ($_POST['sub'] == "search"){
    //Do searching
}
else{
    //Run Away....
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Why does it need to be a submit button, or even a button?

```
<a href="edit.php?id=1">Edit item 1</a>
<a href="edit.php?id=2">Edit item 2</a>
<a href="edit.php?id=3">Edit item 3</a>
<a href="edit.php?id=4">Edit item 4</a>
```